# Calling Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 online from JAVA

Tags: java, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm doing a Dynamics CRM integration from a Java application and I've followed the example from the CRM training kit and managed successfully to connect and create accounts and contacts.
Now I'm having some problems with adding some more fields in the account creation and when connecting a contact with an account.
For instance I cannot create accounts with "address1_freighttermscode" that is a picklist.
My code is the following:

```
private static OrganizationServiceStub.Guid createAccount(OrganizationServiceStub serviceStub, String[] args) {
    try {
        OrganizationServiceStub.Create entry = new OrganizationServiceStub.Create();
        OrganizationServiceStub.Entity newEntryInfo = new OrganizationServiceStub.Entity();
        OrganizationServiceStub.AttributeCollection collection = new OrganizationServiceStub.AttributeCollection();
        if (! (args[0].equals("null") )) {
          OrganizationServiceStub.KeyValuePairOfstringanyType values = new OrganizationServiceStub.KeyValuePairOfstringanyType();
          values.setKey("name");
          values.setValue(args[0]);
          collection.addKeyValuePairOfstringanyType(values);
        }
     if (! (args[13].equals("null"))){
          OrganizationServiceStub.KeyValuePairOfstringanyType incoterm = new OrganizationServiceStub.KeyValuePairOfstringanyType();
          incoterm.setKey("address1_freighttermscode");
          incoterm.setValue(args[13]);
          collection.addKeyValuePairOfstringanyType(incoterm);
        }

        newEntryInfo.setAttributes(collection);

        newEntryInfo.setLogicalName("account");

        entry.setEntity(newEntryInfo);

        OrganizationServiceStub.CreateResponse createResponse = serviceStub.create(entry);
        OrganizationServiceStub.Guid createResultGuid = createResponse.getCreateResult();

        System.out.println("New Account GUID: " + createResultGuid.getGuid());

        return createResultGuid;
    } catch (IOrganizationService_Create_OrganizationServiceFaultFault_FaultMessage e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
    }

    return null;
}
```

When it executes, I get this error

```
[ERROR] Incorrect attribute value type System.String
```

Does anyone have examples on how to handle picklists or lookups?

To connect the contact with the account I'm filling the fields `parentcustomerid` and `parentcustomeridtype` with the GUID from the account and with "account", but the contact does not get associated with the account.

Comment: May I ask why you're doing that from Java? I can think of a couple of reasons but I'd like to know the specific one of yours.

Comment: Did your answer get answered? If so, please check the reply as an answer. Otherwise, please tell what more you'd need.

Comment: Hi Konrad, i still don't have an answer. I'm doing that from java because i'm calling from an oracle stored procedure, and that´s the way i invoke webservices from there.

Comment: I though it was a situation like that. Well, I gave you an answer below, not sure if you've seen it. If you need more help, place a comment in connection to it (to keep the structure of the threads).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set a picklist value you must use an OptionSet and for a lookup you must use an EntityReference. See the SDK's C# documentation, should work the same way using the Axis generated Java code.

```
incoterm.setKey("address1_freighttermscode")   
//assuming the arg is an integer value that matches a picklist value for the attribute    
OptionSetValue freight = new OptionSetValue();
freight.Value = args[13];
incoterm.setValue(freight);    
collection.addKeyValuePairOfstringanyType(incoterm);
```

Comment: thx, the optionset tip worked  just fine. the java equivalent class was OptionSetValue. Now i'm trying for the entityreference, but likewise the classes are different from the C#. I've an EntityReference Class and i think that have to set the logical name and the guid from entity i want to had the reference. is that so?

Comment: For associating the contact with the account should i use also an entityreference for parentcustomerid?

Comment: My mistake on the OptionSetValue, it is the same in Java as C# - I just made a mistake last night, I've corrected my answer.

A Lookup should be EntityReference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.entityreference_members.aspx. Need to set the LogicalName property and the Id property (LogicalName is a string and Id is a Guid.)

Comment: thx, and the parentcustomerid should i do as EntityReference also? i see that there is also a parentcustomeridtype to define the parent as account or contact is that a string?

Comment: finally i've this working, thx for the support. Just on more question, in the optionset i've the description is there anyway i can query them to get the value? thx

Answer (score -1):

I haven't worked with Java for over a decade (and never towards an MS creation like Dynamics) so it might be way off from what you like. :)

You could use the REST web service and call directly to CRM creating your instances. As far I know, that's platform independent and should work as long as you can connect to the exposed service *OrganizationData*.

Comment: from what i saw, invoke the the rest web service from outside CRM can be even more challenging than the SOAP one. At this moment if i could have an example on what to handle objects like picklists, lookups and referenced entities i think i could put this to work just fine.

Comment: Lookups are easy. It's basically a guid to an entity (plus some basic info, the type and name etc.). Picklists are more tricky, because their values are often combined with the organization name hash. Have you made the basic connection/filtration of, say, Contact entities? That's a good starting point.

Comment: Calling the REST web services in Dynamics CRM 2011 from Java is not supported, per the SDK which states that you must access the REST services from within the application (i.e., an authenticated browser session.)

Comment: the tip from Nick, worked with the picklists, trying to solve the rest. thx

Comment: @Nicknow Seriously?! I've made calls from JavaScript placed in an IFRAME linked to external web page. That should definitely count as a call from outside the application, shouldn't it? I haven't tried accessing the data via Java as the OP but the service *OrganizationData* is exposed externally, isn't it? I'll gladly stand corrected if I'm mistaken, though.

Comment: The IFRAME you are referencing was running in a browser session that was authenticated to the Dynamics CRM instance it was calling. That would make it inside the application. It is documented at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334279.aspx. I'm not saying that it can't be done, just that it isn't supported. Using the SOAP endpoints is the correct way to do this.